# How to trigger Initialize method while trying to Unit Test?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I have the override below to do a few things with cookies using the FormsIdentity Object.  But when I instantiate a controller on my Unit Testing this method is not triggered.  Any ideas how to do this?

```
   protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        // Grab the user's login information from FormsAuth
        _userState = new UserState();
        if (this.User.Identity != null && this.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
            this._userState.FromString(((FormsIdentity)this.User.Identity).Ticket.UserData);

        // have to explicitly add this so Master can see untyped value
        this.UserState = _userState;
        //this.ViewData["ErrorDisplay"] = this.ErrorDisplay;

        // custom views should also add these as properties
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Controller.Initialize(RequestContext)` is invoked inside `ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext)`, which in turn can be invoked by the explicit implementation of `IController.Execute(RequestContext)`, so this code will initialize and execute a controller:

```
IController controller = new TestController();
controller.Execute(requestContext);
```

I've analyzed the dependency tree for `Initialize()` and I can't see any other way of invoking this method without resorting to Reflection. You will need to create the `RequestContext` passed to `Execute()` as well, which is easier as it looks like you are using Moq:

```
var wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext);
var requestContext = new RequestContext(wrapper, new RouteData());
```

[This link](http://my6solutions.com/post/2009/08/18/Mocking-HttpContext-in-ASP-NET-MVC.aspx) has helpful details on mocking an HttpContext using Moq.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. I was able to trigger Initialize method, but still getting errors, mocking httpContext is a lot harder than I thought.

Comment: HttpContext is the anti-christ of testability - I try to stay away from it as much as possible, and I'm surprised that Initialize() is so weakly testable as well. Maybe you could look at using a custom model binder or property dependency injection instead of using Initialize() at all?